# Results fixed on webpage

Tags: php, css, laravel

When I try to display content from another blade template, it will only show certain data on the webpage. What I want is inside this page, the content from **test.blade.php** together with the button, when click will pop up a form(I don't want the **test.blade.php** content to be inside). But whenever I try to do it, only certain information is shown and when I view page source, all the data has already been loaded. I have asked this question before already and someone told me it was the fault of my css, but I when I try to look at it, I don't really see anything which is causing this to happen. Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance!

I will put the screenshot here first in the question.

This is what it is suppose to look like where it will have a scroll down bar, and below there should be a button for the popup form.

[image]

But this is what I am getting (I have checked that all the data are already loaded)

[image]

**elements.css** (here is the css that I used)

```
#abc {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .95;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #313131;
  overflow: auto;
}

img#close {
  position: absolute;
  right: -14px;
  top: -14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div#popupContact {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 17%;
  margin-left: -202px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

form {
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: raleway;
  background-color: #fff;
}

p {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

h2 {
  background-color: #FEFFED;
  padding: 20px 35px;
  margin: -10px -50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

hr {
  margin: 10px -50px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 82%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: raleway;
}

#name {
  background-image: url(../images/name.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 7px;
}

#email {
  background-image: url(../images/email.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 7px;
}

textarea {
  background-image: url(../images/msg.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 7px;
  width: 82%;
  height: 95px;
  padding: 10px;
  resize: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: raleway;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#submit {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFBC00;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #FFCB00;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

span {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
}

button {
  width: 10%;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #cd853f;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**evaltest.blade.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Popup form </title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/elements.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-43981329-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
      (function () {
      var ga = document.createElement('script');
      ga.type = 'text/javascript';
      ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- body starts here -->
  <body id ="bdy" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="abc">
      <!-- Popup div starts here -->
      <div id="popupContact">
        <!-- contact us form -->
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/evaltest/'.$data0->id) }}">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <img id ="close" src="{{ URL::to('/image') }}/3.png" onclick ="div_hide()">
          <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$data0->id}}">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2"><b>Recommendation:</b></label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input type="radio" id ="recommendation" name="recommendation" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
              <input type="radio" id ="recommendation" name="recommendation" value="No"> No<br>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
              <input id= "submit" type="submit" href="javascript: check_empty()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- Popup Div Ends Here -->
      // @include('test')
      //it will show all data if I were to put here but I don't want to put it together with the popup form
    </div>
    <!-- Display Popup Button -->
    //this will show a few info but no button       
    @include('test')
    <h1>Click Button to Evaluate</h1>
    <button id="popup" onclick="div_show()">Popup</button>
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/my_js.js') }}"></script>
    //this will show even lesser info but button is shown
    //@include('test')
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.blade.php** (there are more information inside but I only put some as an example of how I got the information)

```
<div class="container">
  @foreach ($data as $object)
    <b>Name: </b>{{ $object->Name }}<br><br>
    <b>Alias: </b>{{ $object->Alias }}<br><br>
    <b>Email: </b>{{$object->Email}}<br><br>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

I have tried removing some of the things inside the css but nothing happen, I even try removing those with the `position: fixed` and also added `.container` but it still doesn't work.

**myjs.js**

```
// function to display popup
function div_show() {
  document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
}

// function to hide popup
function div_hide(){
  document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the `div_show()` JS function?

Comment: @johnEllmore added the JS inside

Comment: It's unfortunately not clear what you're asking for. Can you explain what this application is for? Maybe list out the steps of the process to show the error?  It's hard to infer from what you have here.

Comment: I am trying to make a page where it will show all the test.blade.php with the evaltest.blade.php button. So I decided to combine them together inside evaltest.blade.php but for some reason it only show me a few information of test.blade.php as shown in my screenshot, it suppose to show more than that. I have also checked that the data is already loaded so there shouldn't be any reason for it to be missing

Comment: So the cause should either be the css (as mentioned by someone in another question) or the way that I combine/use test.blade.php

Comment: When you say the data is "loaded", do you mean that the HTML was generated and appears in the source of the page? Just not visually when the page is rendered?

Comment: Yup, so when I right click view page source in my browser, all the data are shown but it is not showing in the page itself

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out how to show my data is that I have to remove the `style="overflow:hidden;"` part so that it will work